# Unityのコードでエラーが出ます: Non-invocable member 'GameManager.clearEf' cannot be used like a method

Tags: c#, unity3d

### 発生している問題

Unity初心者です。
本を参考にタップゲームのアプリを作成しているのですが、エラーにハマってしまい悩んでおります。

該当の行を確認するのですが、エラー文章で検索しても思うような回答が得られず困っております。

```
Non-invocable member 'GameManager.clearEf' cannot be used like a method.
```

何故GameManagerに指摘が来るのか、まだ仕組みが分かっておらずエラーの読み取り方が分かりません。

どなたかご存知でしたら教えていただけると幸いです。

---

### Unityで表示されるエラーメッセージ

```
Assets/Scripts/GameManager.cs(99,13): error CS1955: Non-invocable member 'GameManager.clearEf' cannot be used like a method.
Assets/Scripts/GameManager.cs(129,54): error CS0103: The name 'lvup_efPrefab' does not exist in the current context
Assets/Scripts/GameManager.cs(139,55): error CS0103: The name 'lvup_efPrefab' does not exist in the current context
```

---

### ソースコード

**【GameManager.cs】**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour {
//定数定義
private const int MAX_ORB = 10; //オーブ最大数
private const int RESPAWN_TIME = 5; //オーブが発生する秒数
private const int MAX_LEVEL = 2; //最大レベル

//オブジェクト参照
public GameObject orbPrefab; //オーブのプレハブ指定
public GameObject lvupEf; //レベルアップ時のエフェクト
public GameObject canvasGame; //ゲームキャンバス
public GameObject textScore; //スコアテキスト
public GameObject lvupImage; //レベルアップイラスト
public GameObject clearEf; //ゲームをクリアした際のエフェクト

//メンバ変数
private int score = 0; //現在のスコア
private int nextScore = 10; //レベルアップまでに必要なスコア

private int currentOrb = 0; //現在のオーブ数

private int levelRank = 0; //レベルランク

private DateTime lastDateTime; //前回のオーブを生成した時間

private int [] nextScoreTable = new int[]  {10, 10, 10} ; //レベルアップ数

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start() {
        //初期オーブ生成
        currentOrb = 10;
        for (int i = 0; i < currentOrb; i++) {
            CreateOrb ();
        }

        //初期設定（スタートメソッド内で画像を初期状態へセットする。
        lastDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
        nextScore = nextScoreTable [levelRank];
        lvupImage.GetComponent<ObjectManager> ().SetLvupPicture(levelRank);

        RefreshScoreText ();
    }    

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() {
        if (currentOrb < MAX_ORB) {
            TimeSpan timeSpan = DateTime.UtcNow - lastDateTime;

            if(timeSpan >= TimeSpan.FromSeconds (RESPAWN_TIME)) {
                while (timeSpan >= TimeSpan.FromSeconds (RESPAWN_TIME)) {
                    createNewOrb ();
                    timeSpan -= TimeSpan.FromSeconds (RESPAWN_TIME);
                }
            }

        }
    }


    //新しいオーブの生成
    public void createNewOrb () {
        lastDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
        if (currentOrb >= MAX_ORB) {
            return;
        }
        CreateOrb ();
        currentOrb++;
    }

    //オーブ生成
    public void CreateOrb () {
        GameObject orb = (GameObject)Instantiate (orbPrefab);
        orb.transform.SetParent (canvasGame.transform, false);
        orb.transform.localPosition = new Vector3 (
            UnityEngine.Random.Range (-300.0f, 300.0f),
            UnityEngine.Random.Range (-140.0f, -500.0f),
            0f);
    }

    //オーブ入手
    public void GetOrb () {
        score += 1;

        if (score > nextScore) {
            score = nextScore;
        } 

        LevelUp ();
        RefreshScoreText ();

        //ゲームクリア判定
        if ((score == nextScore) && (levelRank == MAX_LEVEL)) {
            clearEf ();
        }

        currentOrb--;
    }

    //スコアテキスト更新
    void RefreshScoreText () {
        textScore.GetComponent<Text> ().text =
        "オーブ: " + score + " / " + nextScore;
    }

    //画像のレベル管理
    void LevelUp () {
        if (score >= nextScore) {
            if (levelRank < MAX_LEVEL) {
                levelRank++;
                score = 0;

                LevelUp ();

                nextScore = nextScoreTable [levelRank];
                lvupImage.GetComponent<ObjectManager> ().SetLvupPicture (levelRank);

            }
        }
    }

    //レベルアップ時の演出
    void LevelUpEffect () {
        GameObject lvupEf = (GameObject)Instantiate (lvup_efPrefab);

        lvupEf.transform.SetParent(canvasGame.transform, false);
        lvupEf.transform.SetSiblingIndex (2);

        Destroy (lvupEf, 0.5f);
    }

    //レベルが限界値まで到達した時の演出
    void ClearEffect () {
        GameObject clearEf = (GameObject)Instantiate (lvup_efPrefab);
        clearEf.transform.SetParent (canvasGame.transform, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: >supa様　編集ありがとうございます、エラーメッセージと検索した文面もマークダウンするように気を付けます

Answer (score 1):

```
//ゲームクリア判定
        if ((score == nextScore) && (levelRank == MAX_LEVEL)) {
            clearEf ();
        }
```

```
//ゲームクリア判定
        if ((score == nextScore) && (levelRank == MAX_LEVEL)) {
            clearEffect ();
        }
```

じゃないでしょうか

追加編集
コード変更

```
//オブジェクト参照
public GameObject orbPrefab; //オーブのプレハブ指定
// ↓要りません
//public GameObject lvupEf; //レベルアップ時のエフェクト
public GameObject canvasGame; //ゲームキャンバス
public GameObject textScore; //スコアテキスト
public GameObject lvupImage; //レベルアップイラスト
// ↓要りません
//public GameObject clearEf; //ゲームをクリアした際のエフェクト
// ↓追加
[SerializeField]
private GameObject lvup_efPrefab;
```

```
 //レベルアップ時の演出
    void LevelUpEffect () {
                         // ↓変更
        GameObject lvupEf = Instantiate(lvup_efPrefab) as GameObject;

        lvupEf.transform.SetParent(canvasGame.transform, false);
        lvupEf.transform.SetSiblingIndex (2);

        Destroy (lvupEf, 0.5f);
    }
```

```
//レベルが限界値まで到達した時の演出
    void ClearEffect () {
                          // ↓変更
        GameObject clearEf = Instantiate(lvup_efPrefab) as GameObject;
        clearEf.transform.SetParent (canvasGame.transform, false);
    }
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます、コードを修正すると以下のようなエラー文に
差し代わりました。こちらのエラー文の内容を追ってみようと思います。

```
Assets/Scripts/GameManager.cs(99,13): error CS0103: The name 'clearEffect' does not exist in the current context
Assets/Scripts/GameManager.cs(129,54): error CS0103: The name 'lvup_efPrefab' does not exist in the current context
Assets/Scripts/GameManager.cs(139,55): error CS0103: The name 'lvup_efPrefab' does not exist in the current context

```

Comment: このエラーはスクリプト内に"lvup_efPrefab"が存在しないということです。
なので、"lvup_efPrefab"をGameObjectとして新たに追加しましょう。
また、宣言が重複しているモノがあります。
あと、可能な限りpublicを使わないようにしましょう。
[SerializeField]を使うことで、privateでもインスペクタービューで可視化/操作することができます。